# SQLAlchemy: Suffix table name to output columns

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a query where I join multiple tables with similar column names. To disambiguate them, I want to suffix the table name to the column name like: `<column_name>_<table_name>`. There are hundreds of columns in each table, so I would like to do it programmatically.

Is there a way to do something like?

```
sa.select([
    table1.c.suffix('_1'),
    table2.c.suffix('_2')]).
select_from(table1.join(table2, table1.c.id == table2.c.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `label` keyword:

```
sa.select([
    table1.c.column_name.label('_1'),
    table2.c.column_name.label('_2')]).
select_from(table1.join(table2, table1.c.id == table2.c.id))
```

This will allow you to have the same column name from different tables.

If you have a table that is dynamic, or tons of columns, your best bet will be to do something like this:

**pseudo code:**

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'my_table"
```

get the results from a query

```
return_columns = []
counter = 0
for r in results:
    counter += 1
    return_columns.append("`table_name`.`" + r.column_name + "` as col_{}".format(counter))
```

Creating dynamic sql will require you to do a bit of building out. I do this in my application all the time. Except I don't use information schema. I have a table which has my column names in it.

This should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I have hundreds of columns. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: @user1742188 I've updated my answer to include some pseudo code which can lead you in the right direction. It will take some finagling based on your current structure and code, but this is how you can do it.